# Vala GtkButton.Clicked.Connect not calling function

Tags: gtk3, vala

I'm still trying to learn vala and I am having a problem with GtkButton Signals.

I want to connect a function `void refresh ()` to a GtkButton. When the Button is clicked the function should be called and set the Label of a GtkLabel. So I write `GtkButton.clicked.connect (this.function);`. This should call the function when I click on the button, right?

My function is very simple for testing and should change the text of a GtkLabel. So I get `void function () { GtkLabel.label = "New Text"; }`.

When I test this litte program clicking on the button does nothing or at least I can't see anything.

What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
namespace Zeiterfassunggtk {
    [GtkTemplate (ui = "/org/gnome/Zeiterfassunggtk/window.ui")]
    public class Window : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {
        [GtkChild]
        Gtk.Button refreshbutton;
        Gtk.Button menubuttonrefresh;

        void refresh () {
            label1.label = "Clicked";
        }

        public Window (Gtk.Application app) {
            Object (application: app);

            refreshbutton.clicked.connect (this.refresh);
            menubuttonrefresh.clicked.connect (this.refresh);

            this.show_all ();
        }
    }
}
```

you can look at the full code at [github.com](https://github.com/zege-at/ZeiterfassungGtk/blob/master/src/window.vala)

Comment: I rolled back to revision 1 of your question, because the question should always contain the original problem. Otherwise comments and answers are weird for people that see the question the first time. I also edited apmasells answer with the working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `[GtkChild]` on every field if they are in the template. Right now, `menurefresh` contains null and won't be connected to anything. `label1` is also null, so changing its label won't do anything.

The correct code is:

```
namespace Zeiterfassunggtk {
    [GtkTemplate (ui = "/org/gnome/Zeiterfassunggtk/window.ui")]
    public class Window : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {
        [GtkChild]
        Gtk.Button refreshbutton;
        [GtkChild]
        Gtk.Button menubuttonrefresh;
        [GtkChild]
        Gtk.Label label1;

        void refresh () {
            label1.label = "Clicked";
        }

        public Window (Gtk.Application app) {
            Object (application: app);

            refreshbutton.clicked.connect (this.refresh);
            menubuttonrefresh.clicked.connect (this.refresh);

            this.show_all ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me a example on where to add `[GtkChild]`in my code. I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: OK, i played a little bit and found the Solution. Thank You.